# Как передать данные другому окну и запретить возвращаться назад?

Tags: flutter, dart

У меня есть 2 окна.Первое это, например, **loginScreen()**.В нём я хочу перейти на второе окно **mainScreen()** и передать туда данные:

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MainScreen(token: "qwerty"),
    )
);
```

Но из-за `Navigator.push` сверху слева появляется кнопка назад

[image]

Почитал,что эту кнопку можно убрать при помощи

```
AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false
)
```

Но тогда при нажатии аппаратной кнопки назад, он всё равно возвращается на первое окно **loginScreen()**.Как мне тогда менять окно?

Comment: Тут описаны две независимые задачи: передать данные при навигации, и запретить переход назад - соотв., должно быть два вопроса.

Comment: @yar85 но например `navigator.pushandremoveuntil` меняет окно и вместе с этим запрещает возвращаться назад, но сюда нельзя вставить данные для передачи.Поэтому я думаю есть какой-то способ сделать это одной функцией

Comment: Ок, если хочешь "или все, или ничего" - дело твое, не настаиваю конечно.

Comment: @yar85 я знаю как сделать эти 2 вещи по отдельности,А как вместе сделать не знаю, поэтому разделять вопросы не имеет смысла

Comment: _«я знаю как сделать эти 2 вещи по отдельности»_ - тогда почему бы не добавить в вoпрос отдельные решения? (тем самым значительно повысив и конкретику, и вероятность ответа. Относящиеся к проблематике технические детали очень полезны)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html), если он возвращает `false`, то переход назад по нажатию системной кнопкой будет проигнорировано.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  MainScreen({Key key, this.title}) :super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    return false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Main Screen"),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Main Screen"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

А вам точно нужен `Navigator.push`? Просто для вашего случая больше подходит [Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushAndRemoveUntil.html), который удалит предыдущую историю навигации. Вот пример:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MainScreen(token: "qwerty"),
    ),
    (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
);
```